# what are xllcorner and yllcorner for South America?

Tags: gis, arcgis

I have  a map of south America,I want to plug it in a global map of which the projection is WGS84  using arcGIS. In order to put on right place ,xllcorner and yllcorner have to be assigned in ASCII file correctly.I have been searching thru internet but didn't find the right values.any suggestions or help

Comment: I would ask this question on the GIS stackexchange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no general coordinates for the lowerleft corner of south america. This all heavily depends on the map you are using, and its coordinate system. I think the best thing you can do is to georectify your image to get the correct projection.